# How can I convert Google+ to a system app without buying Titanium Pro?

Tags: cyanogenmod, google-plus

The *Locations* feature on Google+ running on Cyanogenmod is not showing a Map. I am not sure what's the cause of this, but as of [CYAN-1193](https://jira.cyanogenmod.org/browse/CYAN-1193) the fix is to convert Google+ to a system app. I did this successfully with Titanium Pro with just one click. After Google+ became a system app, the map was shown.

Now I have a dozen other devices without the pro version of Titanium where I want to do the same. Surely there is a way with *root* and `adb`. Can you guide me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the process to work, requirements are:

1. Titanium Backup zip file, *see below*
2. The license key file `TitaniumBackup_license.txt`.

The idea being, is copy the license file and install the app onto the new device.

## Caveat Emptor

- This is only for legitimate licensed Titanium Backup owners.
- Device is rooted
- USB cable plugged into device
- Functioning copy of `adb`.

### Step 1.

Easiest way, is to generate the Titanium Backup zip file,

- Tap menu
- scroll to the bottom, titled 'Special Features'
- Tap on "*create 'update.zip'*"

  - Scripting Type - **Edify** *Default*
  - Titanium Backup will be installed as - **User application** *Default*
  - Select the name of the output file - **TitaniumBackup-6.1.0.zip** *Tap that selection*

This will create the appropriate zip file on the `/sdcard`.

- Pull that zip file across to your PC, as in `adb pull /sdcard/TitaniumBackup-6.1.0.zip`.
- Unzip it, the file to look for is `data/app/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup.apk`

### Step 2.

Pull the license file across to PC, as in `adb pull /sdcard/TitaniumBackup_license.txt`

## Final step.

Now with both steps completed, it's a matter of:

- pushing the license file across to the new device as in `adb push TitaniumBackup_license.txt /sdcard`. *It must be the root of the SDCard, anywhere else, it fails!*
- install the apk, as in `adb install data/app/com.keramidas.TitaniumBackup.apk`

Now launch the Titanium Backup, it **should** pick up the license file and treat it as Pro version. In the event it does not, its likely a very weird glitch in the application, try reboot the device, to see if it works, if not, report it to the developers. (*I have this problem on my Xperia Mini, have a valid license, and it does not recognize it despite having the license in the root directory of the SDCard!*)

## The hardcore way

This will apply to any app. Gist of these steps, is to move the application to `/system/app`.

- Remount the system as re-writeable, `adb remount`
- Shell in via `adb` and invoke `su`, `adb shell` followed by `su`.
- Move the app from the `/data/app` to `/system/app` directory

For example:

- an app called `fooBarApp`
- its underlying name is `/data/app/fooBarApp-1.apk`

So without further ado:

- `cp /data/app/fooBarApp-1.apk /system/app/fooBarApp.apk` (*we need to drop the `-1` part of the name as system apps do not have them*)
- `rm /data/app/fooBarApp-1.apk` (*To avoid duplication!*)
- At this point, the ownership may get clobbered, or the permissions, for that matter, so make it `chmod 644 /system/app/fooBarApp.apk`
- Reboot